EF Core: Global Query Filter limitation
EF Core Documentation have following limitation for the Global Query Filters:

Filters can only be defined for the root Entity Type of an inheritance hierarchy.

However, let's assume that I have a following model:
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class ChildClass : BaseClass
{
    public string Property { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}

And I apply Global Query Filter on derived entity (ChildClass), not on the root entity (BaseClass):
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<ChildClass>().HasQueryFilter(x => x.Property == "test");
}

Then in the below code Global Query Filter works:
using var dbContext = new MyDbContext();
dbContext.Childs.Add(new ChildClass());
dbContext.Childs.Add(new ChildClass() { Property = "test" });

dbContext.SaveChanges();

// global query filter works
var entities = dbContext.Childs.ToArray();

Am I overlooking something? Is EF Core documentation wrong and I can apply Global Query Filters to derived entities as well?

Do you register BaseClass as an entity anywehere? If not, it's not a base entity type

I don't register it as an entity anywhere. Then the problem seems to be my understanding of the 'base entity type' term.

In EF or any other ORM an entity is a type that's registered with the ORM for mapping to the database.

Alright, I assumed that registering ChildClass as an entity would automatically register its base type (BaseType) as a root entity as well. However, it seems I was mistaken in this assumption.

@Qwertyluk, if you do not call modelBuilder.Entity< BaseClass>(), BaseClass is not registered as entity which should be mapped to database.

You probably found out that modelBuilder.Entity<BaseClass>().HasQueryFilter(... maps BaseClass as entity type, which clearly is not what you want.
In general, if you want to add the same configuration for subclasses of a base type, but only map these subtypes, one possibility is to create a generic configuration class and add subclasses:
class BaseClassConfig<TBaseClass> : IEntityTypeConfiguration<TBaseClass>
    where TBaseClass : BaseClass
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TSubClass> builder)
    {
        builder.HasQueryFilter(x => x.Property == "test");
    }
}

class SubClass1Config : BaseClassConfig<SubClass1> { }
class SubClass2Config : BaseClassConfig<SubClass2> { }

Which could be added to the ModelBuilder separately, or by adding them from the assembly:
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(this.GetType().Assembly);
}

EF recognizes that the generic IEntityTypeConfiguration class can't be mapped and ignores it graciously (it doesn't throw an exception).
